# ASP.NET POST-DATA truncated at 49152 bytes (48K)

Tags: asp.net, postdata

I'm getting errors where viewstate couldn't be decoded, and some of the errors trace to the fact that http post data was truncated at exactly 48K (49152) bytes.

This was [**listed**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945757) as one of the [**fixed**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925248) bugs in .NET 2.0 SP1. I currently have .NET 3.5 SP1.

This problem doesn't seem to happen with every post. Any ideas?

> **[KB 945757](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945757)** Problems that are fixed in the .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1
>
> **[KB 925248](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925248)** FIX: The data in a POST request is truncated to 49,152 bytes when an ASP.NET-connected application receives the POST request

EDIT: Caught one of these errors in my error logs after I added encoding designation to the form. It shows the content-type was properly set to url-encoded, and the content-length was over 49152. But the dump of post data in the error log was again exactly 49152 bytes. I was able to re-create this by clicking the submit button several times from the page. I think the user did this because the page processes very slowly for some reason (was much faster before). It's likely the subsequent submissions that encountered this truncation. My fix might be to make the page fast again and/or disable the button from the first click.

Comment: compress it, cut it, disable the non use viewstate data, re-design your program to not post this huge amount of data.

Comment: @Aristos, unfortunately it's already compressed, and the code is inherited and big, change won't happen soon enough. On the other hand 48K just doesn't seem a reasonable limit on post data, viewstate or not.

Answer (score 1):

I do know that **IIS5** had this problem, **it would truncate** all data above 48Kb except if the form was sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, try to set this as your `content-type` like:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" 
      enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ... >

</form>
```

The [pen-tester](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_test) can bring this issue up.

If you also search for **HTTP Smuggling** you will find the same issue.

you can [read more](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Splitting/Smuggling_%28OWASP-DV-016%29) info on HTTP Smuggling.

Comment: Do you know if IIS6 still has the bug? That's what we're using.

Comment: don't have an IIS6 to test, only 7. but, did you try the form attribute `enctype`, does it work correctly?

Comment: Yes I did add enctype. Don't know if it fixed the problem, because it was a random error that didn't happen all the time.

Comment: log everything until you find if it still happens... either use IIS Logs or a custom log... keep an eye on it, but theoretically, it should avoid the problem with this trick.

Answer (score 1):

i ran into this once and it turned out  it's the browser that is truncating it!

i don't remember which one anymore though.  I want to say it was firefox, but i can't be sure.

the fix was to change the content type of the form to `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: All of my users are on various versions of IE, and this problem was reported at least for IE7 and 8. But I haven't seen one from IE9, though I only have a small number of samples.

Comment: is your form type multipart?  like i said, i don't remember if it was firefox for sure.  check your form type

Comment: When I check in F12 and Fiddler, the form is url encoded, not multipart. But then again I've never seen this error happen myself, I only see this in error reports (emailed to me by the site) that indicate the postdata is cut off.

Comment: like balexandre  change it over and keep an eye on your logs.